# PHP uploading images twice (when it shouldn't) with move_uploaded_file

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file

I created a form where you upload an image like this

```html
 <form class="form" method="post" action="recipeUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="window.location.reload();">
  
  <fieldset style="margin-bottom: 70px;padding-top: 70px;">
  <legend style="font-size: 36px;">פרטים אישיים</legend>
  
  <input class="inForm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="שם"  required/>
  
  <input class="inForm" type="text" name="sur-name" placeholder="שם משפחה" required/>
   </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="margin-bottom: 70px;padding-top: 70px;">
   <legend style="font-size: 36px; ">פרטי המתכון</legend>
   
  <fieldset class="inForm" style="width:max-content;">
   
  <legend style="font-size: 36px">העלו תמונה של המתכון</legend>
   <label class="action" id="bb">בחרו תמונה
   <input id="file" class="inForm" type="file" name="myfile" accept="image/*" required>
   </label>
   <div id="name"></div>
</fieldset>
  <input class="inForm" type="text" name="time" placeholder="זמן הכנה" required/>

  <input class="inForm" type="text" name="meal" placeholder="שם המנה" required/>
  <label class="inForm">בחרו קטגוריה מתאימה</label>
  <select class="inForm" name="category" required/>
  <option value="מנות ראשונות">מנות ראשונות</option>
   <option value="בשר">בשר</option>
   <option value="פחמימות">פחמימות</option>
   <option value="דברי חלב">דברי חלב</option>
   <option value="צמחוני">צמחוני</option>
   <option value="סלטים">סלטים</option>
   <option value="קינוחים">קינוחים</option>
   <option value="אחר">אחר</option>
  </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset style="margin-bottom: 70px;padding-top: 70px;">
  <legend style="font-size: 36px;">המתכון עצמו</legend>
  <textarea id="ingredients" name="ingredients" class="inForm long-text" placeholder="רכיבים" required>רכיבים:</textarea>
   <textarea id="directions" name="directions" class="inForm long-text" placeholder="אופן ההכנה" required>אופן ההכנה:</textarea>
  </fieldset>
 <input class="inForm action" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="שלחו את המתכון שלכם">
  </form>
```

Now the php for uploading the images:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        echo "<label class='inForm'> Your messege has been sent. Thank You!</label>";
         $errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here
$fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$tmp =explode('.',$fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($tmp));
$directory = getcwd(). "/uploads/"; $files = scandir($directory);



$num_files=count($files)-2;

    if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
        $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
          $uploadPath = getcwd() ."/uploads/img[" .$num_files. "].". $fileExtension;
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {

} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
    }

}
```

I tested this many times, and every time I submit the form it uploads the same image under 2 different numbers. let's say there where 0 images in the directory and I would submit the form once it would upload the same image twice under img[0].png and img[1].png where the image is again the same. Why is the code running twice? can sombody help me? Thank you.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reloading the page on form submit: `onSubmit="window.location.reload();"`, this is submitting the form again on reload. Try removing `onSubmit="window.location.reload();"`.

Comment: I will check this in about an hour and see if this is correct. thank you!

Comment: @daniel Visser I coped both the files as it is and ran code on my machine, that uploaded only one file to uploads directory, i have not removed window.location.reload(); from FORM ...i think its not due to window.location.reload(); but something else in INTODAN's code

Comment: it is fixed now.